# strait query produces results. sp_execute sql does not

Tags: sql-server, resultset, dynamic-sql

Maybe I'm going blind.  I can't figure out why this query

```
select * from sys.tables where name = N'foobar'
```

produces the row for that table but

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select * from sys.tables where name = N''@TableName''
', N'@TableName nvarchar(128)',@TableName=N'foobar'
```

returns no rows.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

No quotes required in your query.

exec sp_executesql N'select * from sys.tables where name = @TableName', N'@TableName nvarchar(128)',@TableName=N'foobar'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql